# Solving 4th degree polynomials

Tags: polynomials

I am feeling difficulty to find the roots of this 4th degree polynomial:

$$2x^4+18x^3+58x^2+72x+24=0$$

Factorization methods have been tried.

Comment: Hints: two real and two imaginary roots. Try $x = -2$. Try graphing, try http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quartic_function#Nature_of_the_roots

Comment: start by dividing by $2$.

Answer (score 1):

Notice $x=-2$ is a root.

$(x+2)(x^3 + 7x^2 +15x + 6)$

Using the formula for the solutions of a cubic equation one can find the remaining three solutions:
$$x=\frac{1}{3} \left(\sqrt[3]{\frac{97}{2}-\frac{9 \sqrt{113}}{2}}+\sqrt[3]{\frac{1}{2} \left(97+9 \sqrt{113}\right)}-7\right)$$
$$x=-\frac{1}{6} \sqrt[3]{\frac{97}{2}-\frac{9 \sqrt{113}}{2}} \left(1-i \sqrt{3}\right)-\frac{1}{6} \left(1+i \sqrt{3}\right) \sqrt[3]{\frac{1}{2}
\left(97+9 \sqrt{113}\right)}-\frac{7}{3}$$
$$x=-\frac{1}{6} \sqrt[3]{\frac{1}{2} \left(97+9 \sqrt{113}\right)} \left(1-i \sqrt{3}\right)-\frac{1}{6} \left(1+i \sqrt{3}\right) \sqrt[3]{\frac{97}{2}-\frac{9
\sqrt{113}}{2}}-\frac{7}{3}$$

Comment: Heh. Nobody is going to remember that on a test or competition. Good thought though. :P

Answer (score 0):

$$ 2x^4 + 18x^3 + 58x^2 + 72x + 24 = 0 $$
Divide both sides by $2$ to get: $$ x^4 + 9x^3 + 29x^2 + 36x + 12 = 0 $$Now, use the Rational Roots Theorem to note that $x=-2$ is a root. This is the only "simple" root. You can divide the quartic by $x+2$ to get a cubic which will contain the remaining roots, which aren't nice, so that's the furthest anybody can go.